# How to get path from public/images storage symlink?

Tags: php, laravel, symlink

I have created a symlink to my local storage "(php artisan storage:link)" then, I save images on my public folder like that

```
public function store(PostStoreRequest $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();
    if($request->hasFile('postImage')) {
        $path = $request->file('postImage')->store('public/images');
        $validated['postImage'] = $path;
    }

    $post = auth()->user()->posts()->create($validated);
    $post->categories()->attach($request->category);
    return redirect()->route('articulos.index');
}
```

the $path contains `public/images/IdC24xVkoFZiJFWtyKQ2T1xBVrS0GGU3d2Z4NXgP.jpeg` for example, it stores the image on storage/app/public/images.

Then in blade I show the image like that:

```
<img class="card-custom-img-post" src="{{ asset('storage/'.$post->postImage) }}">
```

It generate this URL: `http://localhost/project/public/storage/public/images/IdC24xVkoFZiJFWtyKQ2T1xBVrS0GGU3d2Z4NXgP.jpeg`

But the correct one is:
`http://localhost/project/public/storage/images/IdC24xVkoFZiJFWtyKQ2T1xBVrS0GGU3d2Z4NXgP.jpeg`

Anyway to get the correct url without replacing or anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions:

You do not save "public/" string in the path (your path will be "images/...").

Or a little workaround:

```
<img class="card-custom-img-post" src="{{ asset('storage/' . str_replace("public/", "", $post->postImage)) }}">
```

Comment: If I just put $path = $request->file('postImage')->store('images'); it creates a folder images on storage/app/images and isn't accesible since its not in public folder

Comment: you have to save to public/images, but in the database you save the path without "public/" folder

Comment: so i'm forced to replace that public from the url? It's hard to beleive there isn't a way to get the correct path